# How to read a string from a file and set it as the text of a label in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, label

I have been trying to set a string read from a file as the text of a widget but it doesn't appear on the window when I run the program. Please help me and show me the way to do it. I have read the file and save it in a list. I want to set the list elements to the text of the labels.

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

f = open("C:\\Users\\Foo\\some_text.txt","r")
some_string = f.read()

my_label = Label(root, text=str(some_string)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```